# Getting Parameter '{browser}' is required by @Configuration on method setup but has not been marked @Optional or defined(Tried solutions)

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I am running tests via selenium grid. I have been getting aforementioned error.
Following are the solutions I tried

1. Tried running tests from testng.xml
2. Set the template for testng.xml from testng properties

The error persisted

My testg file is as follows

```
<suite name="TestSuite" thread-count="2" parallel="tests">
    <listeners>
    <listener class-name="com.hrmapp.orangehrm.Tests.ExtentListener"></listener>
    </listeners>
    <test name="tests">
    <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"></parameter>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.hrmapp.orangehrm.Tests.OrangeHRMTests"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="tests2">
    <parameter name="browser" value="firefox"></parameter>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.hrmapp.orangehrm.Tests.OrangeHRMTests"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

My java class looks like this

```
@Parameters("{browser}")
    @BeforeClass
    public void setup(String browser) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(browser);
        launch(browser);
    }



 public static void launch(String browser) throws MalformedURLException{
        prop=PropertyReader.readData();
        setDriver(browser);
//      setDriver(prop.getProperty("browser"));
        getDriver().manage().window().maximize();
        getDriver().get(prop.getProperty("url"));
    }
```

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue got resolved after I corrected the syntax of parameters

The correct syntax is

```
Parameter({"browser"})
```

and 
not

```
Parameter("{browser}")
```

Comment: not working for me still, can you bit ellaborate

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass browser parameters Before test, since your setup value for test in .xml.

```
@BeforeTest(alwaysTrue = true)
@Parameters("{browser}")
    public void setup(String browser) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(browser);
        launch(browser);
    }
```

Let me know if not gonna work, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to execute below code and let us know if it works

```
    @Parameters("browser")
    @BeforeClass
    public void setup(String browser) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(browser);
        launch(browser);
    }
```